# Reading lines from file only after hastag symbol Python::

Tags: python, readlines

I am trying to read lines from file in python, I searched and found partition/strip however, I got the following error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'partition'
"
file is as the following:

```
`    1 
     2
    [[1],[2],[3],np.repeat(3,4)]   #It's ok 
     # I would like to read last line but without #it's ok)
```

I got a way to read last line without #it's ok,
is there any better and faster way to read only what I want from the beginning not all the line then remove the part that I do not want:

```
 import numpy as np
 import os
 import os.path
  f    = open('trial_one.dat')
  data = f.readlines()
  dir=data[2]
  f.close()

 LE=dir
 LE=LE.partition("#")[0]
 LE = LE.rstrip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
 with open('trial_one.dat', 'r') as f:
     data = f.readlines()
     data = [(d+' ')[:d.find('#')].rstrip() for d in data]
     LE = data[2]
```

The code above removes all comments. Instead if you need to remove the comment from line 2 then:

```
 with open('trial_one.dat', 'r') as f:
     data = f.readlines()
     LE = data[2]
     LE = (LE+' ')[:LE.find('#')].rstrip()
```